# Mapbox - sourced vector file unable to add fill color

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

The code below works without `fill-color` and renders the imported vectors. However, adding `fill-color` causes nothing to be rendered. I've tried changing `type` to `fill` but I still get nothing rendered with a `fill-color`. The tileset is composed of geojsons Polygons that were imported into Mapbox studio tilesets.

`map.addLayer({
        id: 'zip-codes',
        type: 'line',
        source: {
          type: 'vector',
          url: 'mapbox://<tilesetid>',
        },
        'source-layer': 'original',
        layout: {
          'line-join': 'round',
          'line-cap': 'round',
        },
        paint: {
          'line-color': 'green',
          'line-width': 10,
          'fill-color': 'red',
        },
      });`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A polygon layer in Mapbox-GL-JS is either a `fill` or a `line`, not both. If it's `fill` it only contains `fill-*` properties. If it's `line`, it only contains `line-` properties.

So if you want filled polygons, you probably want something like:

```
map.addLayer({
    id: 'zip-codes',
    type: 'fill',
    source: {
      type: 'vector',
      url: 'mapbox://<tilesetid>',
    },
    'source-layer': 'original',
    paint: {
      'fill-color': 'red',
    },
  });
```

If you want to control both fill and border, you need two separate layers: one with type `fill` and one with type `line`.

Comment: part of the confusion for me was looking in the API to no avail. The information needed for more detail is in the style spec: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#layers-fill